# JFace - select editable cell at given row index?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, tableviewer

**EDIT:** Here's the code based on Max's suggestion

```
    editor.getControl().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            Table table = viewer.getTable();
            int currentIndex = table.getSelectionIndex();

            if (e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_DOWN) {
                if (currentIndex != table.getItemCount() - 1) {
                    table.setSelection(currentIndex+1);

                    IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection) viewer.getSelection();
                    Object rowObj = sel.getFirstElement();

                    viewer.editElement(rowObj, columnIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I have a JFace TableViewer with a column that is editable (done by implementing `EditingSupport`).

I want the user to be able to press the up/down arrows when editing a cell to move to the row above/below it. Here's what I have:

```
final TextCellEditor editor = new TextCellEditor(viewer.getTable());

editor.getControl().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_DOWN) {
            Table table = viewer.getTable();
            int currentIndex = table.getSelectionIndex();

            if (currentIndex != table.getItemCount() - 1) {
                table.setSelection(currentIndex+1);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This moves the selected row to the next row, but doesn't move the textbox, i.e. after pressing down arrow it looks like this:

[image]

How do I set the textbox to the cell in a a particular row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the method:

```
org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.editElement(Object element, int column)
```